# how to configure security group in amazon EC2

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rightscale

I am new to this Aws security to deploy in amazon webservice.
When i restrict security groups with some IP address, my application runs dead slow or it may not run also, thats the reason i am getting connection time out when i try to call webservice which is deployed in aws. When i open the IP address restriction in Security groups it works fine.

How to configure my AWS using security groups. so that my application is accessible to only to some restricted networks.
Please help me put on this.

Below are the my security group details

```
INBOUND   
Type     Protocol       Port range      Source       
MYSQL       TCP             3306            X.X.X.X/X   
SSH         TCP             22              X.X.X.X/X    
HTTP        TCP             80              X.X.X.X/X

OUBOUND  
Type    Protocol        Port range      Source  
MYSQL       TCP             3306            0.0.0.0/0  
SSH         TCP             22              0.0.0.0/0  
HTTP        TCP             80              0.0.0.0/0
```

i am using hibernate for DB connection from my web application. But everytime i am getting connection timeout with the above security group. but if i remove the IP address restrictions it works fine. 
Note: DB connection works fine from mysql workbench

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://schemaname.amazonDBInsatnce:3306/test</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Security Groups** will not "slow down" access to an Amazon EC2 instance. They are used to determine which ports are open to a given range of IP addresses. Either the traffic is allowed through, or it is not.

Security Groups can be defined for **Inbound** and **Outbound** traffic. By default, all Inbound traffic is denied and all Outbound traffic is permitted.

It is possible that your application is trying to access some external service and is **timing-out**, hence causing delays. Permitted all Outbound traffic is usually acceptable, so try that first and see if your application performs better.

Also, check the **log files** that your application is producing to see if any errors are being generated, which will give you a hint as to what might be happening.

Comment: Please check the edited question and let me know if anything helps me out.

Comment: Is your database on the same instance as the webserver? If so, you don't need to open any ports for it, since that traffic does not enter or leave the instance. Outbound settings are for traffic that leaves the server -- you probably don't need them configured. In fact, try opening Outbound to All Traffic and see whether that avoids time-outs -- it could be that a service on your instance is trying to reach the Internet but failing. Also, you don't need 3306 open for Inbound traffic -- that would only be used for another machine to communicate inwards to your instance.

Comment: the database instance is in the same as webserver. The issue got solved. Instead of IP address, i gave security group ID, and it worked perfectly. I am not sure what could be the reason. I am exploring myself to the reason and will post once i will get my findings.

Comment: Ah! If your security group was referring to a Public IP address, and if your software pointed to the database via that Public IP address, then the traffic effectively exits the instance, bounces off the "edge" of the internet, then comes back in. If your database is on the same machine as the webserver, then the webserver would be best to use "localhost" as the machine name. This would keep the traffic totally within the instance and there would be no need to mention the database in the security groups.